# Повторно запустить код Python

Tags: python

Прошу прощения за детский вопрос, но подскажите пожалуйста, я совсем новичок в программировании 
Написал просто для изучения программу, в которой при вводе названия страны отображается название столицы.
Проблема в том, что после того как результат отображается программа перестает работать, как сделать, чтобы она запускалась повторно, чтобы можно было выбрать еще например другую страну, а выход был после ввода команды Exit\выход.

```
print('Тут можно узнать столицу данных стран')
print(' Россия \n США \n Финляндия \n Франция \n Италия \n Украина \n Испания \n')


russia = "Москва"
usa = "Вашингтнон"
suomi = "Хельсинки"
france = 'Париж'
italy = 'Рим'
ukrane = 'Киев'
spain = "Мадрид"


a = input('Введи название страны, чтобы узнать столицу ') 
if a == 'Россия':
    print(russia)
elif a =="США":
    print(usa)
elif a == 'Финляндия':
    print(suomi)
elif a == "Франция":
    print(france)
elif a == "Италия":
    print(itali)
elif a == 'Украина':
    print(ukrane)
elif a == 'Испания':
    print(spain)
```

Comment: Организуйте бесконечный цикл, или условие для выхода из цикла.

Answer (score 1):

Немного глупое, но все же работающее решение:

```
f=True
while(f==True):
    t = input("Введите 'начать', чтобы начать или 'выйти', чтобы выйти >>> ")
    if t=="начать":
        print('Тут можно узнать столицу данных стран')
        print(' Россия \n США \n Финляндия \n Франция \n Италия \n Украина \n Испания \n')


        russia = "Москва"
        usa = "Вашингтнон"
        suomi = "Хельсинки"
        france = 'Париж'
        italy = 'Рим'
        ukrane = 'Киев'
        spain = "Мадрид"


        a = input('Введи название страны, чтобы узнать столицу ')
        if a == 'Россия':
            print(russia)
        elif a =="США":
            print(usa)
        elif a == 'Финляндия':
            print(suomi)
        elif a == "Франция":
            print(france)
        elif a == "Италия":
            print(italy)
        elif a == 'Украина':
            print(ukrane)
        elif a == 'Испания':
            print(spain)
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_coutry(text):
    return view(input(text))


def view(country):
    if country == 'Россия':
        print(russia)
        get_coutry('поищем ещё? вводи название страны')
    elif country == 'США':
        print(usa)
        get_coutry('можем продолжить, введи другую страну')

get_coutry('вводи')
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно делать с помощью функций:

```
countries = {'Россия': "Москва",
         'США': "Вашингтнон",
         'Финляндия': "Хельсинки",
         'Франция': 'Париж',
         'Италия': 'Рим',
         'Украина': 'Киев',
         'Испания': "Мадрид"}

def print_country(country_name):
   try:
       if country_name == '':
           exit()
       print(countries[country_name])
   except KeyError:
      print('Ошибка! Проверьте правильность введеных даннных')


def running():
   print_country(input('Введите название страны или нажмите ENTER, чтобы 
   выйти:').strip())

while True:
   running()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    print('Тут можно узнать столицу данных стран')
    print(' Россия \n США \n Финляндия \n Франция \n Италия \n Украина \n Испания \n')
    russia = "Москва"
    usa = "Вашингтнон"
    suomi = "Хельсинки"
    france = 'Париж'
    italy = 'Рим'
    ukrane = 'Киев'
    spain = "Мадрид"
    a = input('Введи название страны, чтобы узнать столицу ') 
    if a == 'Россия':
        print(russia)
    elif a =="США":
        print(usa)
    elif a == 'Финляндия':
        print(suomi)
    elif a == "Франция":
        print(france)
    elif a == "Италия":
        print(itali)
    elif a == 'Украина':
        print(ukrane)
    elif a == 'Испания':
        print(spain)
    if a=="Выход" or a=="Exit":
        break
```